# Search bar not showing on modal presentation view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I had an application in which I need to show a search bar on top of a `UITableView`. I am presenting the modal presentation like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
searchViewController *formmodal1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchViewController"];

// UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:formmodal1];
// present the controller
// on iPad, this will be a Popover
// on iPhone, this will be an action sheet

formmodal1.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

formmodal1.delegate=self;
UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [formmodal1 popoverPresentationController];
popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;

popController.presentedViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(350,350);
popController.sourceView = sender;
popController.sourceRect = btn.bounds;
formmodal1.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:formmodal1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here I am facing an issue like the search bar is not showing. The full view is taken over by `UITableView`. I am adding search bar on top position of the `UIViewController`,and after that I am adding `UITableView` bellow that. Can anybody help to find out where I am going wrong?

---

Comment: Why don't you just add the searchbar and tableView in storyboard?

Comment: Try 3D rendering of the app screen on runtime and check if the searchbar is already there below the tableview.

Comment: @abhi1992 i am doing that only

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @abhi1992 no .it is not coming when presentation style is popover

Comment: If you are directly presenting it will come?  check `preferredContentSize `

Comment: @abhi1992 yes.by presenting it as pop over only it is not showing